# What's the difference between declaring a variable and a namespace in a TypeScript declaration file

Tags: typescript, typescript-declarations, typescript-namespace

I'm creating TypeScript declarations for a module. The module has a default export with 2 functions: `foo` and `bar` and is used as follows:

```
import myModule from 'my-module';

myModule.foo();
myModule.bar();
```

I have created a `.d.ts` file, inside which I can add types to the module by declaring a variable:

```
declare var myModule: {
    foo(): void;
    bar(): void;
};

export default myModule;
```

or by declaring a namespace:

```
declare namespace MyModule {
    function foo(): void;
    function bar(): void;
}

export default MyModule;
```

What is the difference between these options? Is one of them preferred, or should I be using something else entirely?

Comment: 1 is a variable declaration that has an object for its type. The other is a namespace.

Comment: @kelsny Is there any practical difference between those for this purpose?